# How to convert string to existing attribute in model when creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a array of strings, I want to retrieve for each the attribute during the creation of the post.

My array = `["_646_maturity", "_660_maturity", "_651_maturity", "_652_maturity", "_641_maturity"]`

```
class Audit < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user

  before_save :calculate_scoring

  def calculate_scoring
    scoring = []

    models = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.collect{|t| t.underscore.singularize.camelize.constantize rescue nil}
    columns = models.collect{|m| m.column_names rescue nil}

    columns[2].each do |c|
      if c.include? "maturity"
        Rails.logger.debug 'COLUMN : '+c.inspect
        scoring.push(c)
      end
    end

    getMaturity = ""

    scoring.each do |e|
       getMaturity = e.to_sym.inspect
       Rails.logger.debug 'MATURITY : '+getMaturity
    end


  end

end
```

The log print > `'MATURITY : :_651_maturity'`

I'm looking to the value of `:_651_maturity` who is a attribute of my post.

I tried `.to_sym` but it's not working..

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you retrieving all the tables and their columns if you just need one of them (`columns[2]`). Do you have a model for that table?

Comment: `columns` return a object with `{ nil, nil, { all the columns} }` so in fact, I'm getting all the columns with `columns[2]`

Comment: Still, do you need a particular table or all of them?

Comment: All of them. The problem is I can't get the values inside the loop because they are strings and not the relation with the post created ..
The log print > `":_651_maturity"` and I'm looking to the value of `:_651_maturity`who is a attribute of my post.

Comment: I still don't get it. When you say 'my post' which table do you refer to? Is there a model for it?

Comment: This method `:calculate_scoring` is execute on `before_save` Audit. The code above is the model of the Audit, which is a kind of post.

If I put directly inside my method `value = :_651_maturity`, I will get the value.

I want to do it dynamic, but I don't know how to convert these strings to relations from the post creation.

It's hard to explain sorry ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `calculate_scoring` you can use `self` to point to the record you are saving. So `self._651_maturity = <some_value>`, `self[:_651_maturity] = <some_value>` and `self['_651_maturity']` are all valid methods to set `_651_maturity`.

Also, you can do something like:

```rb
my_attrib = '_651_maturity'
self[my_attrib] = 'foo'
```